# Como puedo enviar 2 arrays distintos desde php a ajax? O si se mandan juntos como sería el proceso para separarlos?

Tags: php, ajax, web

Eh revisado por muchas partes y solo encuentro como enviar varias variables o arreglos desde Ajax a php, pero no como hacerlo al contrario, quiero que el sussess me pueda devolver 2 arrays totalmente distintos

O si se envían los 2 en uno solo, como hago, primero en php para unirlos

Y 2 como haría en Ajax para separalos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu no le mandas cosas a AJAX.

AJAX es el que te las pide a ti, o en otro caso, el que te las manda a ti. Cuando digo a ti me refiero a PHP.

Si lo que quieres es obtener 2 arrays que tienes en php. Debes llamar a ese script de PHP desde AJAX. Y el response de esa llamada contendrá tus 2 arrays.

Un ejemplo (usando jQuery) podría ser:

```
$.get("doble_array.php", function(data, status) {
    let arrays = JSON.parse(data);
    let array_1 = arrays[0];
    let array_2 = arrays[1];
});
```

Puedes hacerlo nativamente con javascript usando fetch o XMLHttpRequest.

Para en PHP devolver un JSON con 2 arrays usamos el siguiente codigo

```
<?php

$array_1 = array(5, 4, 3);
$array_2 = array(12, 20, 25);

$array_3 = array();

array_push($array_3, $array_1);
array_push($array_3, $array_2);

echo json_encode($array_3);

?>
```

Con un output:

```
[[5,4,3],[12,20,25]]
```

Comment: si pero la pregunta es como php le retorna los 2 arrays distintos al ajax

Comment: Deberia retornar un json en lugar de un solo array, podria guardar los 2 arrays dentro de un 3er array, parsear ese 3er array a json y devolverlo

Comment: darioxlz, justamente es como lo estaba pensando, pero no sé cómo hacer el proceso del parseo y luego separarlos cuando ya esté en el Javascript

Comment: Deja modifico mi respuesta y te muestro como

Comment: @DiegoAndrésEstrada listo

Comment: @DiegoAndrésEstrada también puse como recibir y parsear la data que obtienes mediante AJAX

Comment: Gracias Bro, fue de mucha ayuda